# Advanced Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Given two lists:

```
chars = ['ab', 'bc', 'ca']
words = ['abc', 'bca', 'dac', 'dbc', 'cba']
```

how can you use list comprehensions to generate a filtered list of `words` by the following condition: given that each word is of length `n` and `chars` is of length `n` as well, the filtered list should include only words that each `i`-th character is in the `i`-th string in `words`.

In this case, we should get `['abc', 'bca']` as a result.

(If this looks familiar to anyone, this was one of the questions in the previous Google code jam)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[w for w in words if all([w[i] in chars[i] for i in range(len(w))])]
```

Comment: Frankly, I prefer @SilentGhost's answer.

Answer (score 21):

```
>>> [word for word in words if all(l in chars[i] for i, l in enumerate(word))]
['abc', 'bca']
```

Answer (score 4):

Using zip:

```
[w for w in words if all([a in c for a, c in zip(w, chars)])]
```

or using enumerate:

```
[w for w in words if not [w for i, c in enumerate(chars) if w[i] not in c]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, using `index`:

```
[words[chars.index(char)] for char in chars if char in words[chars.index(char)]]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does not match the strings like 'bcc','bbc' etc. Additionally 'char.index' will break if the list 'chars' contains duplicate strings.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple approach:

```
yourlist = [ w for w in words for ch in chars if w.startswith(ch) ]
```

Comment: Omitted condition "each i-th character is in the i-th string in words".

Answer (score -1):

Why so complex? This works as well:

```
[words[x] for x in range(len(chars)) if chars[x] in words[x]]
```

Comment: this wouldn't catch the word 'bbc'